# How to build a 32-bit compat libselinux on (and for use on) an x86-64 Centos system

Tags: rpm, yum, centos7, libselinux

I need a 32-bit compat libselinux.so.1 on my x86-64 Centos system to run some non-open source software from Xilinx. I tried installing with yum:

```
$ sudo yum install libselinux-devel.i686
```

However, I found that the package is apparently broken as the link to libselinux.so in /lib (which points to /lib/libselinux.so.1) is broken (/lib/libselinux.so.1 does not exist)... so apparently that package is broken at this point.

So now I need to build the libselinux-devel.src.rpm so that it's actually a 32-bit lib that would then get installed on my x86-64 Centos 7 system.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Use mock to build libselinux-devel.i686 in an i686 chroot.